# Android 9 does not save proxy information

Tags: android

I have an `Galaxy S8 Android 9`, i need to connect the device to a proxy. So, i do the following:

1. Select the connected Wifi
2. Navigate to Advanced option
3. Set Proxy as Manual
4. Set Proxy hostname as: The IP of my proxy (192.168.51.25)
5. Set the port number 8889
6. ***Finally I save the configuration***

But, it seems that this config is never saved. When i click on back, and navigate back to advanced feature then it seems that it is not saved.

[I found the exact problem in this link](https://forums.androidcentral.com/android-pie/941905-samsung-galaxy-s9-plus-after-update-android-9-pie-wi-fi-proxy-setting-wont-stick.html), but did not get any proper answer from it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the problem with below approach:

1. Forget the active network
2. Find the forgeted wifi
3. Add credentials
4. Click on Advance
5. Add the proxy
6. Save

   ---

If you update your Android , it might be help.